# What is the best practice to Manage Facade pattern for EJB session bean?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, entitymanager, facade

**Hello,**

I would like to know the best practice for managing Facades. 
The main objective of my project:
Once connected via a login system, we arrive on our account page. Depending on the status of the user (project manager or executant) we can access either the project itself as well as each of its phases (status: project manager) or phases only (status: executant).
In this project, i use entities, i created a persistence unit, and used the Facade pattern to manipulate my database. 
In my Netbeans, if I do `New > Sessions Bean for Entity Classes`, and let say that I select Example entity, then Netbeans would generate `public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {...}` with many methode and

```
 @Stateless
public class ExampleFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> {...}
```

for all entities i have select. For all Facade i use one ManagerBean and i use :

```
@EJB
    private ExampleFacade exempleFacade;
```

in him .
I have a problem recovering data from other bean managers because for get projet or phase i have use `@RequestScope` because in .xhtml get param in URL. After search on google, i understand why i can't .
For resolv my problem, i have create a general manager for all facade.
My project works perfectly but I want to know if it's the best practice and if it's secure?
I ask myself it's a question to progress in my learning of jee and jsf

This is my generalManager

```
package logic;

import facade.PhasesFacade;
import facade.PostesFacade;
import facade.ProjetsFacade;
import facade.UtilisateursFacade;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.Phases;
import model.Projets;
import model.Utilisateurs;

/**
 *
 * @author valibert
 */

@Named(value = "generalManager")
@SessionScoped
public class GeneralManager implements Serializable {

    private Utilisateurs currentUser;
    private Projets currentProjet;
    private Phases currentPhase;

    ArrayList<Utilisateurs> listUtilisateurs;
    ArrayList<Projets> listProjets;
    ArrayList<Phases> listPhases;

    private String validForm;
    private String mailUtil;
    private String mdpUtil;
    private int idProjet;

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.idProjet}")
    private String idProjetResquest;

    @EJB
    private PhasesFacade phasesFacade;

    @EJB
    private PostesFacade postesFacade;

    @EJB
    private ProjetsFacade projetsFacade;

    @EJB
    private UtilisateursFacade utilisateursFacade;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of generalManager
     */
    public GeneralManager() {

    }

    public Utilisateurs getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(Utilisateurs currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public Projets getCurrentProjet() {
        return currentProjet;
    }

    public void setCurrentProjet(Projets currentProjet) {
        this.currentProjet = currentProjet;
    }

    public Phases getCurrentPhase() {
        return currentPhase;
    }

    public void setCurrentPhase(Phases currentPhase) {
        this.currentPhase = currentPhase;
    }

    public ArrayList<Utilisateurs> getListUtilisateurs() {
        return listUtilisateurs;
    }

    public void setListUtilisateurs(ArrayList<Utilisateurs> listUtilisateurs) {
        this.listUtilisateurs = listUtilisateurs;
    }

    public ArrayList<Projets> getListProjets() {
        return listProjets;
    }

    public void setListProjets(ArrayList<Projets> listProjets) {
        this.listProjets = listProjets;
    }

    public ArrayList<Phases> getListPhases() {
        return listPhases;
    }

    public void setListPhases(ArrayList<Phases> listPhases) {
        this.listPhases = listPhases;
    }

    public PhasesFacade getPhasesFacade() {
        return phasesFacade;
    }

    public void setPhasesFacade(PhasesFacade phasesFacade) {
        this.phasesFacade = phasesFacade;
    }

    public PostesFacade getPostesFacade() {
        return postesFacade;
    }

    public void setPostesFacade(PostesFacade postesFacade) {
        this.postesFacade = postesFacade;
    }

    public ProjetsFacade getProjetsFacade() {
        return projetsFacade;
    }

    public void setProjetsFacade(ProjetsFacade projetsFacade) {
        this.projetsFacade = projetsFacade;
    }

    public UtilisateursFacade getUtilisateursFacade() {
        return utilisateursFacade;
    }

    public void setUtilisateursFacade(UtilisateursFacade utilisateursFacade) {
        this.utilisateursFacade = utilisateursFacade;
    }

    public String getValidForm() {
        return validForm;
    }

    public void setValidForm(String validForm) {
        this.validForm = validForm;
    }

    public String getMailUtil() {
        return mailUtil;
    }

    public void setMailUtil(String mailUtil) {
        this.mailUtil = mailUtil;
    }

    public String getMdpUtil() {
        return mdpUtil;
    }

    public void setMdpUtil(String mdpUtil) {
        this.mdpUtil = mdpUtil;
    }

    public String getIdProjetResquest() {
        return idProjetResquest;
    }

    public void setIdProjetResquest(String idProjetResquest) {
        this.idProjetResquest = idProjetResquest;
    }

    public int getIdProjet() {
        return idProjet;
    }

    public void setIdProjet(int idProjet) {
        this.idProjet = idProjet;
    }

    //Méthode
    public String submitFormLogin(){
        currentUser = utilisateursFacade.findOne(mailUtil);
        if ((utilisateursFacade.findOne(mailUtil).getMdpUtil().equals(mdpUtil)) && (utilisateursFacade.findOne(mailUtil).getMailUtil().equals(mailUtil)) ){
            currentUser = utilisateursFacade.findOne(mailUtil);
            validForm = "toCompteFromIndex";
            return validForm;
        }
        currentUser = new Utilisateurs();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        message.setSummary("L'utilisateur ou le mot de passe n'est pas valide merci de rééssayer");
        message.setDetail("Message detail.");
        context.addMessage("formConnection", message);
        validForm = "";
        return validForm;
    }

    public void onload(){

        try {
            idProjet = Integer.parseInt(idProjetResquest);
            currentProjet = projetsFacade.findByIdAndUserManager(idProjet, currentUser.getIdUtil());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            idProjetResquest = "404";
        }

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void initUtilisateurs(){
        this.listUtilisateurs = new ArrayList();
        this.listUtilisateurs.addAll(utilisateursFacade.findAll());
    }

}
```

and this is a view for example

```
<ui:composition template="/templates.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="idProjet" name="idProjet" value="#{generalManager.idProjetResquest}" required="true" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{generalManager.onload}" />
</f:metadata> 

<ui:define name="content-main">
    <h2>Chef Projet #{generalManager.currentUser.prenomUtil}</h2>
    <h2>Projet  #{generalManager.currentProjet.libelleProj}</h2>

    <p>Date du début du projet :<h:outputText value="#{generalManager.currentProjet.dateDebutProj}" >
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </h:outputText></p>
    <p>Phases du projet</p>
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{generalManager.phasesFacade.findPhaseByProjet(projetsManager.projetChoose.idProjet)}" var="itemPhase">
            <li>
                <h:outputLink value="../phases/View.xhtml" >
                    <f:param name="idPhase" value="#{itemPhase.idPhase}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemPhase.libellePhase}"/>
                </h:outputLink>
            </li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>

</ui:define>
```

thank you in advance